Javafx eclipse Text Input Validate when numeric or Mixed and reject when Non-numeric
In JavaFx eclipse application, before saving the data in SQL data base, it is required to verify following conditions:  Either Numeric Value or Mixed. But,reject if purely non-numeric with(out) special characters like JHGYyree.
Allowed text: 1234, A1254, b64A8 (Ignore Case)
Not Allowed: aasdrgf, ASDSA, Asxss, @#vdvd, @33KJJJ, #@878sasa.
The data entered is to be checked after pressing Enter key or Mouse click on Save Button.
How to write such a function in JavaFX ?
     @FXML
     private Label lblOffName;

     Boolean static input_validation == false;
     String id = txtOffName.getText();

     if(validate_text(id) == true){

    }
    public Boolean validate_text(String str){
    // validation code here ...
   return input_validation;
   }


Some approaches are examined here and here. If you encounter problems, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Do want to restrict the input so that the user can’t input invalid data using a TextFormatter? Or do you want to let the user input anything and then validate at some other time, e.g. by marking the field in error with a highlight and error message when a submit button is pressed?

@jewelsea thanks.. the text is to be tested after pressing Enter key or mouse click

You'll need an OnAction EventHandler for your button.  Check the TextField content in that EventHandler and display an Alert if it fails.

Dear Devel, I am stuck how to write Regex or function for validation TextField contents. I need help to write logic in the function validate_text().. mentioned in the post... I shall call validate_text() in the EventHandler.

This is just a vanilla Java question and not JavaFX-specific.  If you asked it on the Java tag with no JavaFX involved in the question, you probably would have quickly received many useful answers.

Example
An example solution using a loop (assumes a basic English character set).  You could use regex instead, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.
package application;

public class InputValidator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testData = {
                // valid 
                "1234", "A1254", "b64A8",
                // invalid
                "aasdrgf", "ASDSA", "Asxss", "@#vdvd", "@33KJJJ", "#@878sasa"
        };

        for (String input: testData) {
            validate(input);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Either Numeric Value like or Mixed. 
     * But, to reject if purely non-numeric with(out) 
     * special characters like JHGYyree.
     *
     * @param input string to validate
     * @return true if the input string is value.
     */
    private static boolean validate(String input) {
        boolean hasDigit = false;
        boolean hasAlpha = false;
        boolean hasSpecial = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i));

            if (isDigit(c)) {
                hasDigit = true;
            }

            if (isAlpha(c)) {
                hasAlpha = true;
            }

            if (!isDigit(c) && !isAlpha(c)) {
                hasSpecial = true;
            }
        }

        boolean isValid =
                (hasDigit && !hasAlpha && !hasSpecial) || (hasDigit && hasAlpha && !hasSpecial);

        System.out.println(input + " > " + isValid);

        return isValid;
    }

    private static boolean isDigit(char c) {
        return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
    }

    private static boolean isAlpha(char c) {
        return 'a' <= c && c <= 'z';
    }
}

Output
1234 > true
A1254 > true
b64A8 > true
aasdrgf > false
ASDSA > false
Asxss > false
@#vdvd > false
@33KJJJ > false
#@878sasa > false

Integration with JavaFX
I will also leave this as an exercise for the reader.
Either you can write the integration code yourself, or leverage a validation framework such as:

ControlsFX Validation
MaterialFX validation


thanks for this code ... I used it i my application ..  In future will try to put same functionality using Regex and update here ..
